# can not publish config.json under angular application domain

Tags: json, angular, webpack, micro-frontend, config.json

I need to publish my config.json file with angular.json under my application domain. config.json is located in src folder. I expose one of my module as mfe, which uses this config.json, i have not access to that file in shell, so i need this file to be available from shell.

i tried to publish it as styles, in angular.json i wrote
{
input: path to the file,
bundleName: any name,
inject: false,
}
but that does not works. i get cors error when i make a request, because it is not hosted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i can not publish code since it is my organisation's